# Use Lagrange multiplier to find the distance between the point $(3,4,0)$ and the surface of the cone $z^2=x^2+y^2$

Tags: multivariable-calculus, optimization, lagrange-multiplier

> Use Lagrange multiplier to find the distance between the point $(3,4,0)$ and the surface of the cone  $$ z^2=x^2+y^2 $$

I wrote the equation of the distance:
$$f(x,y,z)=(x-3)^2+(y-4)^2+z^2$$

and ended up with the following equations:
\begin{align} 2(x-3)&=2x \lambda,\\ 2(y-4)&=\lambda2y,\\2z&= -2z \lambda, \\z^2&= x^2 + y^2.
\end{align}
Solving the equations I get $x=\frac{3}{2}$ , $y=2$ and $z=\pm \frac{5}{2}$. 
Can you help me solve this, because I am confused, I don't know if I should solve the case where $z=0$ and $z \neq 0$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look at the third equation $2z=-2z\lambda$. If $z\ne 0$ we get $\lambda=-1$, and that  quickly leads to your solutions.

We *do have to consider* the possibility $z=0$. If $z=0$, that tells us nothing about $\lambda$, but it forces $x=y=0$, because of $x^2+y^2=z^2$.
Now check whether $x=0$, $y=0$ satisfies your first two equations. It doesn't.  So the only remaining candidates are the ones that you found.